# Get current user in kernel.request or kernel.request events in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service in which I inject the TokenStorage and want to get the curent user.

```
/**
 *
 * @Service("liip_theme.theme_request_listener")
 * @Tag("kernel.event_listener", attributes={ "event"="kernel.request", "method"="onKernelRequest" })
 */
class ThemeRequestListener
{
    private $sam;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "sam" = @Inject("security.token_storage")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorage $sam)
    {

        $this->sam = $sam;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $a = $this->sam->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting

```
Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null
```

I don't get this when I `var_dump($a)`, but when I run the website normally it crashes with this error. I've also deleted cache and restarted apache. I also am sure I am logged in. Var_dump()-ing it works and retrieves the curent user, but without dumping it, the website crashes.

Looking around I found out it could be related to listener priority, but I've added:

```
* @Tag("kernel.event_listener", attributes={ "event"="kernel.request", "method"="onKernelRequest","priority"=0 })
```

And changed 0 to -1, -255, 255, 1, and nothing happened.

Am I doing something wrong or is it JMSDIExtraBundle's fault?

I've also defined it like so:

```
liip_theme.theme_request_listener:
    class: Application\Liip\ThemeBundle\EventListener\ThemeRequestListener
    arguments: [ @security.token_storage ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 0 }
```

So it's not from JMSDI.

Another thing, it crashes only in the DEV environment. I get a Symfony toolbar crash with alert. In PROD it works fine. But I still want to solve it.

It can't be another bundle as I've tried with a fresh new 2.8.3 project with no vendor bundle aside the standard ones, just this listener and getting the same error.

Opened a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18056).

Comment: You have a custom data collector for profiler?

Comment: Not made by me, but only ones that I seem to find are `sonata.block.data_collector` and `form.type_extension.form.data_collector` both from sonata bundles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$token = $this->sam->getToken();
$a = $token ? $token->getUser() : null;
```

TokenStorage::getToken can return null.

Comment: Can it return null when a user is logged in?

Comment: If called before security listeners or if another listener set null.

Comment: Then how can I call it after security? I need to know the user inside it, but it will always return it null.

Comment: You say "I don't get this when I var_dump($a), but when I run the website normally it crashes with this error", var_dump retrieves user one time (if call var_dump and continue work)?

Comment: That's the strange part, the value is there when I dump it, but it is null when running it normally. Probably Symfony tries to manage things in a certain order.

Comment: Try set null checking as in my answer and run normally, what you see about user in profiler?

Comment: I see the curent user as normally, but if I try to do $a->getUsername() it will crash like before. $a is always null no matter what. Another thing, it crashes only in the DEV environment. I get a Symfony toolbar crash with alert. In PROD it works fine. But I still want to solve it.

Comment: This kind of problems (profiler toolbar crash) is most often due to a bad server configuration or a syntax error inside your project. Try to browse your app at `localhost:8000` after run `app/console server:run` instead of browse it through your webserver, that can helps to avoid doubts about server configuration.

Comment: I've ran the clean 2.8.3 install with that and it still crashes. Now I've ran my project and it crashes, too. Doubt it's from the configuration, either. Running php 5.6.8, by the way.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why `getToken()` was returning `null`.  I'm having the same issue and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

The Firewall Service gets called after the Kernel that's because there is no User object created. First check if the Token is != null, like @ArturVesker said.